# Communication between nodes ROS (Python)

Tags: python, ros

I want to create two nodes that communicate with each other. I want node1 to receive information from node2 and perform some operations (for example, the sum of information in nodes 1 and 2) and vice-versa. How can I implement it? This is the code of Node1 so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String

def callback(msg):
    print '%s' % msg.data


def nodo():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('chatter1', String, queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node('nodo1', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber('chatter2', String, callback)
    rate = rospy.Rate(1) # 10hz
    x = 5
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        for i in range(0,51):
            pos1 = "%s" % (x)
            pub.publish(pos1)
            rate.sleep()
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        nodo()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

This is the code of Node2:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String

def callback(msg):
    print '%s' % msg.data


def nodo():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('chatter2', String, queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node('nodo2', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber('chatter1', String, callback)
    rate = rospy.Rate(1) # 10hz
    x2 = 4
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        for i in range(0,51):
            pos2 = "%s" % (x2)
            pub.publish(pos2)
            rate.sleep()
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        nodo()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

Comment: ROS has a designated [QA forum](http://answers.ros.org/) where you can get a pretty good response. Why don't you open a question there and paste the link to it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `node1` creates itself with a queue of 10, but then `node2` tries to send 51 items to that queue.  `node2` will block until `node1` processes some of the items on the queue.  The trouble is that `node1` is similarly blocked, because it is trying to send 51 items to `node2`.

A cheap and cheerful workround is to set the queue size to 100.  A better solution involves not sending if there is anything in the queue.

Comment: Thanks, but my goal is to take the information sent by node2 and perform a sum with the information in node1.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do something with the information sent by node 2, you have to change the subscriber callback in node 1. The callback is called whenever you receive a message, provided that you called `spin`.

You have to change node 1 so that:

- The code calls `spin` (in your code it does not, it is stuck in the `while`).
- The callback function processes the information in the message and sends it back.

```
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String

pub = None

def callback(msg):
    x = int(msg.data)
    pub.publish(str(x + 5))

def nodo():
    global pub
    rospy.init_node('nodo1', anonymous=True)
    pub = rospy.Publisher('chatter1', String, queue_size=10)
    rospy.Subscriber('chatter2', String, callback)
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        nodo()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```